# Recover data from repartitioned SD card?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, ext4

I had an SD card with an important `.cpp` file. I forgot about this and repartitioned and reformatted the drive. The drive in question was formatted `ext4`. Is it possible for me to recover this file of maximum size of a few KBs?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just use testdisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `testdisk` utility by running:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Then run it by:

```
sudo testdisk <device_name>
```

Replacing *`<device_name>`* with `/dev/sdb` or other depending to your specific configuration.

For testdisk usage read:

```
man testdisk
```

Comment: Nice tool, but did not help.

Comment: @daltonfury42 It always helped me in such cases. Probably you did not use it right. But if you are unfortunate, the file could be overwritten.

Comment: Well, I did a deep search, it listed several partitions, but it said it couldnot recover any files.

Comment: @daltonfury42 That's weird. It almost always can recover most of files. if you did not write much to the disk. But in case of SD deleting files overwrites more blocks than if you use HDD.

Comment: This is what I get: "Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
" Anyway I am leaving it as it is. I've wrote another cpp file from scratch.